# mongoose connection error (on First connect)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got back on a project that I didn't touch for a while and I get this error.

> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-01-ntrwp.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-01-ntrwp.mongodb.net:27017 closed

I checked the connection network access and allowed everyone I checked twice the mongoose.connect CREDENTIAL and I don't see why it keeps sending me this error. I also reinstall npm mongoose.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const placesRoutes = require("./routes/places-routes");
const usersRoutes = require("./routes/users-routes");
const HttpError = require("./models/http-error");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/uploads/images", express.static(path.join("uploads", "images")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE");

  next();
});

app.use("/api/places", placesRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", usersRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new HttpError("Could not find this route.", 404);
  throw error;
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  if (req.file) {
    fs.unlink(req.file.path, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  if (res.headerSent) {
    return next(error);
  }
  res.status(error.code || 500);
  res.json({ message: error.message || "An unknown error occurred!" });
});

mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://XXXX:XXXX@cluster0-ntrwp.mongodb.net/XXXX?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
  )
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(5000);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your mongodb instance on the cloud is running and the url hasn't changed?

Comment: Thank you I fount it.